# Correct use of 国語

Tags: word-choice

Is this correct, is the idea correct?

> メキシコの国語はスペイン語です
>   Spanish is the national language in Mexico

The translators do not show if it can be used like this, also I have seen that it is used to refer to the Japanese language, is it the same to say:

日本語　equals to  国語　?

Comment: Note: your usage is right and the proposition is wrong (technically).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more on what do you mean by proposition?, I don't think I understand the problem.

Comment: I think your statement is not accurate. It reads as if Spanish is the only one has the "national language" status, but to my knowledge they have designated 50+ languages as national languages, so a well-founded sentence would be "Spanish is a national language in Mexico" or スペイン語はメキシコの国語です.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary tells us:

> [１ 一国の主体をなす民族が、共有し、広く使用している言語。その国の公用語・共通語。](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/76750/meaning/m0u/%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E/)
>   Language shared and widely used by the people of a country. The official language of this country.

So your sentence is correct.

The second entry:

> ２ 日本の言語。日本語。

made clear that without context 国語 means 日本語 as you assumed.